# Why doesn't google SSO have JavaScript Validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, web, gmail

I have noticed that Google login form doesn't do any javaScript Validation like null checks etc. General practice is that JS is used as first level of validation, and server side validation as second level . So why do gmail not validate Login pages using JavaScript? Is there any specific security risk or I am missing something?